Running GNUPlot by git bash shell
I tried working on passing command line to GNUPlot by git shell and this was the following code.
#!/bin/bash

cd 'C:/Program Files/gnuplot/bin'
./wgnuplot << EOF
plot sin(x)
EOF


When I run the code, GNUplot is launched well. However, plot of sin(x) never poped up. What should I do?
I tried not using the EOF commands (so, ./wgunplot<<< plot sin(x)) but this made the situation even worser(even gnuplot didn't worked out).

Have you checked help command-line-options ?

I did but it didn't helped me that well.

Gnuplot expects data on standard input, not a script.

@Ori what is the reason that you want to place your gnuplot script in a bash script and not in a text file and simply loading this from the command line?
